# Parsing Swift dictionary's secondary level

Tags: swift, dictionary, request

I have a JSON object that comes from my server as so:

```
LOGIN_SUCCESS with JSON: {
    token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJteS5kb21haW4uY29tIiwic3ViIjoiNTkwOTRkNjRjMmRhN2E3MWI4NTljYTFhIiwiaWF0IjoxNDk0MjY1NTE1LCJleHAiOjE0OTQ4NzAzMTV9.SqsLeToG8-_3CV1Yr4Z4SUIv4-vqGbntGwFLB4i7n-w";
    user =     {
        "__v" = 0;
        "_id" = 59094d64c2da7a71b859ca1a;
        createdAt = "2017-05-03T03:24:20.309Z";
        email = "dylan@msn.com";
        name = Dylan;
        updatedAt = "2017-05-03T03:24:20.309Z";
    };
}
```

This get converted to a dictionary as userInfo.  However, since my token is not returned in userinfo how can I parse this into a class.  Currently, my 
initialization looks like this with hard coded strings:

```
self.loggedInUser.setUser(firstName: "Dylan" as String!,
                          email: "dylan@msn.com"as String!,
                          token: "test" as String!,
                          id: "1"as String!,
                          longitude: "40.0"as String!,
                          latitude: "-70"as String!)

self.loggedInUser.printUser()
```

Full Request Attempt:

```
func loginPost(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (_ userInfo: User?, _ error: [[String : Any]]?) -> Void) {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type" : "application/json"]
        let parameters: Parameters = ["email": "\(email)","password": "\(password)"]

Alamofire.request(loginURL, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
    .responseJSON { response in
        if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
            print("LOGIN_SUCCESS with JSON: \(response.result.value!)")
            if let userInfo = response.value as? [String : Any] {


                self.loggedInUser.setUser(firstName: userInfo.["user"]["name"] as! String!,
                                          email: userInfo["email"] as! String!,
                                          token: userInfo["token"] as! String!,
                                          id: "1"as String!,
                                          longitude: "40.0"as String!,
                                          latitude: "-70"as String!)
                self.loggedInUser.printUser()
                return completion(self.loggedInUser, nil)
            }
        } else {
            print("LOGIN_FAILURE with JSON: \(response.result.value!)")

            if let error = response.result.value as? [[String: Any]] {
                //If you want array of task id you can try like
                return completion(nil, error)
            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Take a look at the [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) framework

Comment: @CodeDifferent thanks I'll take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the corrected code below:

```
if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
            print("LOGIN_SUCCESS with JSON: \(response.result.value!)")
            if let responseData = response.value as? [String : Any] {
                let token = responseData["token"] as? String
                if let userInfo = responseData as? [String : Any] {
                self.loggedInUser.setUser(firstName: userInfo.["user"]["name"] as! String!,
                                          email: userInfo["email"] as! String!,
                                          token: userInfo["token"] as! String!,
                                          id: "1"as String!,
                                          longitude: "40.0"as String!,
                                          latitude: "-70"as String!)
                self.loggedInUser.printUser()
                return completion(self.loggedInUser, nil)
            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ok, so pull the token out first.  How do I access the user data where it is 2D?  For instance: userInfo.["user"]["name"]

Comment: As I am getting a "Type 'Any' has no subscript members" error

Comment: You have to parse them layer by layer if you don't want to use a 3rd party framework.
So first let `user = userInfo["user"] as? [String:Any]` and then `let name = user["name"] as? String`